# Filter lines having text portions embedded either between - or * using regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex

i have to Filter lines having text portions embedded either between - or * using regular expression

```
    zenPython = '''
    The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
    
    Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Explicit is better than implicit.
    Simple is better than complex.
    Complex is better than complicated.
    Flat is better than nested.
    Sparse is better than dense.
    Readability counts.
    Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
    Although practicality beats purity.
    Errors should never pass silently.
    Unless explicitly silenced.
    In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
    There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
    Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
    Now is better than never.
    Although never is often better than *right* now.
    If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
    If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
    Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

    '''
    portions=[]
    fp = io.StringIO(zenPython)
    
    zenlines = fp.readlines()
    
    zenlines = [ line.strip() for line in zenlines ]
    
    patterns = r"[-*] ?([^-*].*?) ?[-*]"
    texts = zenlines
    for line in lines:
      for text in texts:
        if re.search(patterns, text):
            portion = re.findall(patterns,text)
            portions.append(str(portion).replace('[\'','').replace('\']',''))
            return portions
```

output required:

```
['and preferably only one', 'right']
```

but im getting `['and preferably only one']`
can i know why im not getting `('right')`?

Comment: This code does not execute: `NameError: name 'lines' is not defined`

Comment: If you omit `for line in lines` https://repl.it/repls/JumboWhimsicalApplicationserver

Comment: `(?<= \*|--)(.*)(?=\* |--)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ufcagu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As @coelhudo stated in its answer, you do not get the expected result because the `main` function returns as soon as it finds a match.

Simply moving the return statement at the root level of the function fixes the problem (or what we could guess is the problem).

---

That said, there still are problems in your code:

1. The `lines` variable is never set and the `for line in lines:` crashes the function
2. The `"[-*] ?([^-*].*?) ?[-*]"`could match unwanted patterns. For example, the string `*This is not a test-` will match the regular expression ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/NlYB0G/2/)). Using [`([-*]) ?([^-*].*?) ?\1`](https://regex101.com/r/NlYB0G/1) instead ensures that the opening "emphasis" character is the same that the closing one by reusing the value matching the first capturing group.
3. You could access directly the string value of the matches instead of converting the whole match to string and replacing the unwanted characters:

```py
# portions.append(str(portion).replace('[\'','').replace('\']',''))  # hard to understand
portions.append(portion[0])  # much better
```

4. Your code assumes that it will be only one match per line, what is true for the Zen of Python but could be false for any other text. So you should make the code handle this case.

---

Here is a rewrited version of your function addressing the above issues:

```py
import io
import re


EMPHASIS_RE = re.compile(r"([-*]) ?([^-*].*?) ?\1")  # (2) will match only emphasis that start and end with the same character
ZEN = '''
    The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

    Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Explicit is better than implicit.
    Simple is better than complex.
    Complex is better than complicated.
    Flat is better than nested.
    Sparse is better than dense.
    Readability counts.
    Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
    Although practicality beats purity.
    Errors should never pass silently.
    Unless explicitly silenced.
    In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
    There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
    Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
    Now is better than never.
    Although never is often better than *right* now.
    If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
    If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
    Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
'''


def main():
    portions = []
    for line in map(str.strip, ZEN.split('\n')):
        emphasis = EMPHASIS_RE.findall(line)  # (4) find all the matches in the line
        if emphasis:
            # (3) gets directly the wanted part of the matches
            # and (4) add all matches in the line to the portions list
            portions.extend((match[1] for match in emphasis))
    return portions


print(main())  # ['and preferably only one', 'right']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's missing one result because the function main is returning before completing the loop.

Change:

```
for line in lines:
    for text in texts:
        if re.search(patterns, text):
            portion = re.findall(patterns,text)
            portions.append(str(portion).replace('[\'','').replace('\']',''))
            return portions
```

To this:

```
for line in lines:
    for text in texts:
        if re.search(patterns, text):
            portion = re.findall(patterns,text)
            portions.append(str(portion).replace('[\'','').replace('\']',''))
return portions
```